# Thief turned into Alwar

Tags: scripture, alwar

Which alwar was a thief and turned by the Lord to alwar? How many hymns he composed in Divya prabandam? What answers he got from his wife when he said he steals for livelihood?

Answer (score 1):

He is Thirumangai Alwar. He married Kumudavalli Deviyar who was the daughter of a Vaishnavite doctor. Thirumangai   Alwar is a very brave person in fact he was not a thief at first, once he turned into a Vaishnavite, Kumudavalli Deviyar asked him to promise her that he would feed 1008 Vaishnavites daily.

Unable to bear the expenses he resorted to robbery. Since he was a built, muscular and strong person many feared him. Once he stopped a bridegroom and tried to remove the toe ring of the bride but he could not. They were none other than Sriman Narayana and Lakshmi Devi. Lord Narayana himself initiated him by revealing the meaning of the Ashtaaksharam.

From then on he gave up robbing. He composed 6 poems. He is the last of the 12 Alwars.

He has written the following poems,

1. Periya Thirumozhi
2. Tirunedundandaham
3. Siriya Thirumadal
4. Periya Thirumadal
5. Tirukurandandam
6. Thiruvazhuk Koorirupai

Comment: What is the title of his composing? Where is the puranic reference? His wife asked the provisions you get thru stealing you only eat. If we take that sin will catch hold of me and our son. You have left out the answer to the question what his wife told?

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan: [May be from this:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirumangai_Alvar) and [check this also](http://www.divyadesam.com/alwars/thirumangai-alwar.shtml)

Comment: @ddr--I have referred wikipedia and divya desam. Apart from thjis fromany puranas or ithihas can you quote the answer?

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan, Thirumangai Alwar was the last of the Alwars who lived during the Kali Yuga. No Puranas and Ithihasas were composed at that time. All we have are traditional and temple accounts of Thirumangai Alwar's history. So I cannot quote the reference for you.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan I think only Nammalwar is mentioned somewhere in Shriman Bhagwad Mahapurana, no other alwar is ever mentioned in puranas.

Comment: @Yogi Yah, most of the Alwar lived after the Puranic Era.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan, I have given you the answer for the question (most of it, except the last part) can you mark it as the right answer so that people can know for sure. Thanks.

Comment: @nikhil--puranic reference needed--what are the hymns composed? How may are there and what is the tilte?

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan We do not have Puranic presence of Alwars! Most of the Alwars were born during the Kali Yuga except for Pogai, Boothath and Pey Alwar, so no references can be found. But I will edit the answer and write the works he composed.

Comment: Refer vishnu purana etc  u can find- I know the answer. I can give in detail--

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Please quote the lines for me in the Vishnu Purana, I will add them into the answer, let this be a community effort. I have written the works that Thirumangai Alwar has written.

Comment: You have not written the total number of hymns composed--whatever you have written about his works I know because am reading divya prabandam. You have quoted six works by thirumangai alwar. In total how many hymns he has composed was asked inthe question.  Do not expect that your answer is right and expect a tick. Refer keshav srinivasan's answer--the way he quotes with slokas and puranic reference.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Are you really sure that you can find references to the Alwars in the Puranas? Please quote the line for me then. Please understand that you cannot have Puranic references for everything. Only certain things can be quoted from the Puranas. I am aware of Keshav Srinivasan's answering style.  Puranic quotes can only be provided when they are available. In this case they are not.

Comment: @Nikhil--You should search bagavathams also for this. Not only puranas. If you search in depth you can find. I am having 4000 DP meaning and special meaning. Please do not argue meaningless.